# Query SELECT with JS moment date

Tags: mysql, date, select, momentjs

I have a select query with this WHERE clausole:

```
AND Calendario.data = "2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z"
```

This query is executed on 2 different DB, but correctly goes only on one.
In the second one don't catch any error but the query fetch 0 row instead of 1.
In this case, if the WHERE clausole is modified in

```
AND Calendario.data = "2015-10-20"
```

the query fetches the correct number of rows.
Why it happens? Both fields are equal (type DATE, collation utf8_bin).

Comment: What is the exact value stored against Calendario.data = "2015-10-20" in your table which is not working?

Comment: "2015-10-20" exactly the same as in the other db...